# How to create text clipping mask with Adobe XD?

Tags: clipping-mask, adobe-xd

How can I create text clipping masks with Adobe XD? I know you can do this with images, but how about with text?

I know this is possible to do with other Adobe software, but I'd prefer not to install anything else right now.

Example:
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Place some text over an image
2. Right click the text and choose *Path > Convert to Path*
3. Select both text and image
4. Right click and choose *Mask with Shape*
5. If you want, you can add a black rectangle and right click it and choose *Arrange > Send to back*

Example

[image]

Note: Converting text to a path turns the text into a shape, and it will no longer be editable as a text object, and the process is irreversable. If you want to edit the text in future, keep a copy of the editable text somewhere off the artboard.

Answer (score 2):

You can use boolean operations for a non-destructive way to do this:

1. Draw a rectangle covering the entire text
2. Select both and create an Intersect boolean group: 
   [image: boolean operation options] 
   (or Object > Path > Intersect)

If you just want to mask a gradient or image, you can directly apply a gradient or image fill to this boolean object – the fill settings work just like a Path drawn with the Pen tool.

If you want to mask more complex content, like multiple different vector shapes, you can use the boolean object as a mask shape. Place it above all the other content in the Z order, select the content together with the boolean object, and choose Object > Mask With Shape. Then you'll have a structure like this:

[image: Layers and appearance using boolean object as a mask]

Either way, if you want to change the text later, you can still select the Text node and edit it or change its font settings:

[image: selected text after editing]

[image: result after editing text]